# Python URLencoding Specific Results

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests, urlencode

I'm querying from a database in Python 3.8.2

I need the urlencoded results to be:

```
data = {"where":{"date":"03/30/20"}}
needed_results = ?where=%7B%22date%22%3A%20%2203%2F30%2F20%22%7D
```

I've tried the following

```
import urllib.parse

data = {"where":{"date":"03/30/20"}}

print(urllib.parse.quote_plus(data))
```

When I do that I get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Johnathan\Desktop\Python Snippets\test_func.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(urllib.parse.quote_plus(data))
  File "C:\Users\Johnathan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 855, in quote_plus
    string = quote(string, safe + space, encoding, errors)
  File "C:\Users\Johnathan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 839, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Users\Johnathan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 864, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

I've tried a couple of other methods and received:?where=%7B%27date%27%3A+%2703%2F30%2F20%27%7D

Long Story Short, I need to url encode the following

```
data = {"where":{"date":"03/30/20"}}

needed_encoded_data = ?where=%7B%22date%22%3A%20%2203%2F30%2F20%22%7D
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`where` is a dictionary - that can't be url-encoded. You need to turn that into a string or bytes object first.

You can do that with `json.dumps`

```
import json
import urllib.parse

data = {"where":{"date":"03/30/20"}}

print(urllib.parse.quote_plus(json.dumps(data)))
```

Output:

```
%7B%22where%22%3A+%7B%22date%22%3A+%2203%2F30%2F20%22%7D%7D
```